# How to make only positive int field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have posqtresql db. And there is an integer field in table. How to make it only positive?
Not in validation in rails.
I need to make it in migration file

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use check constraints in Postgresql. Rails migrations do not wrap this behavior, so you'll have to write the SQL yourself. [This page in the Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) has a few examples on how to handle this, so be sure to check it out.

Example:

```
def up
  create_table :people do |t|
    t.integer :age
  end

  execute <<-SQL
    ALTER TABLE people ADD CONSTRAINT age CHECK (age > 0);
  SQL
end
```

**Note:** As the [Rails Guides note](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you), if you want to do this **you'll have to use the SQL schema dump format**. This is fairly easy to set up, but it will not allow you to use two+ different database systems (e.g. SQLite in dev and PostgreSQL in production).